# Local images not loading in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to build an image gallery using Vue.js and local images are not loading. I have the `src` attributes set in the data attribute and can only seem to load images from external sources. Example:

```
data() {

        return {
            images: [
              "../assets/images/photos/bathroom/bathroom-1.png",
              "https://i.natgeofe.com/n/46b07b5e-1264-42e1-ae4b-8a021226e2d0/domestic-cat_thumb_square.jpg",
            ],
        };
    },
```

With the rest of my code to scroll through the gallery, the first image doesn't load though the second image does. I figure it's something to with the the way Vue compiles everything, as I can display the image statically with a regular  tag and setting the src manually.

Comment: Can you show your template HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap any relative path in `require()`.
In your case:

```js
export default {
  data: () => ({
    images: [
      require("../assets/images/photos/bathroom/bathroom-1.png"),
      "https://i.natgeofe.com/n/46b07b5e-1264-42e1-ae4b-8a021226e2d0/domestic-cat_thumb_square.jpg"
    ]
  })
}
```

Documentation: [Vue Loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/).

Comment: This worked perfectly! Previously I'd tried including require("path") in the HTML, didn't think you could add it to the array like that.

Comment: @delves, glad to hear my answer was useful. Consider marking it as accepted, to let future users know it's helpful, should they have a similar problem. Questions with accepted answers show up higher in search results.